# C++ variable visable scopes and strems

Tags: c++, pointers, inputstream, poco-libraries

I am newbie in C++ and can't understand some behavior.
Have function below and in this case it works.

```
bool Network::doRequest(HTTPRequest& request, string path, string content) {
  HTTPResponse response;
  istream* respStreamPtr;
  session->sendRequest(request);
  respStreamPtr = &session->receiveResponse(response);
  if (response.getStatus() == HTTPResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)
  {
    credentials->authenticate(request, response);
    session->sendRequest(request);
    respStreamPtr = &session->receiveResponse(response);
  }
  if (response.get("Content-Encoding") == "deflate") {
    Poco::InflatingInputStream inflater(*respStreamPtr);
    respStreamPtr = &std::istream(inflater.rdbuf());
    Logger::dumpStream(*respStreamPtr);
  }
  return true;
}
```

But if move string **Logger::dumpStream(*respStreamPtr);** out of the if block. Like this:

```
  if (response.get("Content-Encoding") == "deflate") {
    Poco::InflatingInputStream inflater(*respStreamPtr);
    respStreamPtr = &std::istream(inflater.rdbuf());
  }
  Logger::dumpStream(*respStreamPtr);
```

It's stop to work!!!
Condition **(response.get("Content-Encoding") == "deflate")** always true;
So trouble with visibility stream content in block.
But I can't understand what I do wrong.
Help me please.

P.S. In both case no exception. In second case just no data in file somefile.txt.
In first case file somefile.txt has inflated data from http request.

```
void Logger::dumpStream(std::istream& inputStream) {  
  fstream outStream("somefile.txt", ios_base::trunc | ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
  outStream << inputStream.rdbuf();
  outStream.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the classes you're using, but it seems very likely that the problem is `Poco::InflatingInputStream inflater` is going out of scope.

Inside the if statement:

```
if (response.get("Content-Encoding") == "deflate") {
   Poco::InflatingInputStream inflater(*respStreamPtr);
   respStreamPtr = &std::istream(inflater.rdbuf());
}
```

`respStreamPtr` is being pointed at a stream which uses a buffer from your `inflater` object. Once the if statement closes, that buffer is no longer valid and therefore you can't use your `respStreamPtr` outside.

Comment: The pointer itself becomes dangling, actually _immediately_. Any other compiler but VS would prohibit this non-standard code. Don't take the address of temporaries.

Comment: Thank you for so quick response.

Please wath UPDATED in main question.

Added new statement inflater = new.
And now it works.
But now i have a memory leaks, cause i do not delete inflate object?

Comment: @greenif Please don't edit questions. The question was answered. If you have additional questions, please make a new post.